# Gentoo install mod_proxy_balancer

Tags: apache, proxy, gentoo

I installed in Apache in Gentoo and i need to use it like a proxy but i am unable to install mod_proxy_balancer. If i restart apache it display the following:

> - apache2 has detected an error in your setup: AH00526: Syntax error
>     on line 4 of /etc/apache2/vhosts.d/jira.conf: Invalid command
>     'ProxyRequests', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not
>     included in the server configuration  * ERROR: apache2 failed to stop

Any suggestion how to?
May seems a easy question for Gentoo expert, but not for beginners.

Comment: Did you add something like APACHE2_MODULES="proxy" in your /etc/make.conf before installing Apache? Did you add -D PROXY to APACHE2_OPTS in /etc/conf.d/apache2?

Answer (score 0):

Please create a new file if not existing:

```
nano /etc/portage/package.use/apache2
```

Add the line containing the following:

> www-servers/apache apache2_modules_proxy_balancer  apache2_modules_slotmem_shm   apache2_modules_proxy slotmem_shm  mod_proxy_balancer mod_proxy   apache2_modules_lbmethod_byrequests apache2_modules_proxy_balancer apache2_modules_slotmem_shm apache2_modules_proxy apache2_modules_proxy_ajp apache2_modules_proxy_balancer  apache2_modules_proxy_http

Please run the following command in order to update the packages:

```
emerge -avDU @world
```

The purpose of this file is to add the following modules when apache2 ( www-servers/apache ) will be installed with the following command:

```
emerge www-servers/apache
```

After apache is installed with the requested modules need to add ( -D PROXY )

```
nano /etc/conf.d/apache2
```

> APACHE2_OPTS="-D DEFAULT_VHOST -D INFO -D SSL -D SSL_DEFAULT_VHOST -D LANGUAGE -D PROXY "

Now we should be ok with the apache modules.